# SQL Query on how often is UAC or Elevation utlized?

Tags: sql, sql-server, uac, sccm

I am working on a project to do some clean up of my environemt. Starting with collecting some information. I am writing a SQL Query to collect the number of users who are local admin's on their PC, but I am not having trouble with the query itself, it's more an issue with finding the right Query Table.

I want to know how many times, a user, who is a local admin on their PC may perform a function or task that; 1.) prompts UAC, and/or how many times the user performs an elevated function as a local admin.

the end goal is to verify if local admin rights are indeed neccasary, or not.

So far, using the following;

```
SELECT * FROM
v_gs_computer_system

v_gs_LocalGroupMembers0 

v_R_User
```

Gets me a decent amount of data in the results but none of the available tables can help tell me how often a user elevates or triggers UAC prompts.

is there a query that possibly pull this data? I am not even fully sure if there is a "UAC Counter" in place, as I have not attempted to collect such data before.

Comment: What's provoking the question?

Answer (score 0):

that information is not collected to SCCM by default. So I don't think that you could find it in the database. Unless we find that how this information is recorded on the client and then put it into WMI by scripts and get it collected by Hardware inventory, then we could find them in the SQL.

Best Regards,
Ray